# Are suggested edits indexed by Google?

Tags: support, status-completed, suggested-edits, google, revisions-list

I was trying to get some more information to complement an answer, and I found this odd link in my search, linking the suggested edit history of a question. Are those pages intended to be indexed by Google?

Below are two screenshots to show exactly what I mean.

[image]

## Clicking on that link leads to a page with the suggested edit history:

[image]

Comment: Are suggested edit outcome pages permanent? Sometimes I leave a link to a rejected suggested edit in a comment if it provides potentially useful information, and I don't want it to rot.

Comment: @Vi. They are preserved indefinitely -- or rather, the database information from which those pages are built is preserved. For example, the edit linked in the screenshot is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/43671). (The URL changed with the introduction of other Review queues, but it redirects).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Good catch -- I will add

```
Disallow: /suggested-edits/
Disallow: /suggested-edits?
```

to our `robots.txt`